# Jgit - For a given repository, how can we identify the list of new commits, and which branch each of these commits are coming from?

Tags: java, git, eclipse-plugin, jgit

I tried getting all the branches and commits for each branch as follow:

```
Repository repo = getRepository();
//fBranchList is a list of branches in that repository
for (String branch : fBranchList) {
    ObjectId commitId = repo.resolve(branchName)
}
```

This approach has some performance issues. Therefore, I want all the commits in a repository and corresponding branch (parent branch) where the commits were originated.

Another approach I was thinking of is as follow:

```
Git git = Git.open(new File("path")) ;
Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();

for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
    if(commit.getParentCount()>1 ){
        System.out.println("LogCommit: " + commit.getName());
}
```

But with this approach, I am not able to get the branch in which commit was committed for the first time.
Can you please help?

Comment: The snippets at https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/WalkAllCommits.java and https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/WalkAllCommits.java show ways to iterate over almost all commits in a repository quickly, but I don't know how you would get the branches that the commit originated on from there...

Comment: I checked all the snippets. None of those has what I am looking for. But, thank you for commenting.